Expo build successfully but does not load anything that is being fetched from firestore. And also crashes when navigating
My react native application works perfectly fine on Expo Go so I thought it would be a successful build. After the apk build finished, the data that is loaded on expo go does not load on the apk and there are no logs (I dont know where it is). this is my current package.json, please tell me what else is needed. Thank you
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@google/generative-ai": "^0.12.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.3.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.7.5",
    "@react-native-segmented-control/segmented-control": "2.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.6.4",
    "@stream-io/flat-list-mvcp": "^0.10.3",
    "dompurify": "^3.1.7",
    "expo": "~51.0.8",
    "expo-av": "~14.0.6",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.10",
    "expo-checkbox": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~6.0.3",
    "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-image": "~1.13.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~12.0.5",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.5",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~16.0.3",
    "expo-sharing": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-video": "^1.2.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "firebase": "^10.12.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "6.7.0",
    "marked": "^14.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.1",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-awesome-gallery": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^5.0.7",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.12.2",
    "react-native-emoji-modal": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.14.0",
    "react-native-markdown-display": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.5",
    "react-native-paper-tabs": "^0.10.4",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^9.3.1",
    "react-native-pinchable": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-reanimated-viewer": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-video": "^6.4.1",
    "stream-chat-expo": "^5.32.1",
    "toastify-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "validator": "^13.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


and this is my eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 12.6.1",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}


I have tried rebuilding it, clearing previous builds but still no progress.

does your api endpoints use http ? if yes you have to enable usesCleartextTraffic or use https

all the APIs i use uses https. I also dont have a backend because I only use firebase client sdk

you can check your logs in released apk using adb command adb logcat | grep "ReactNativeJS" which may helps you for debugging.

Is that for development build or can i also do that with only the Expo Go workflow? I'm new to this

In development you check logs in development server, adb logcat  acts as console where you can find the console.logs or any other logs in production. e.g. your app works find in expo go, but when you build it doesn't. you can still check the logs in build using that command to check what goes wrong in built app.
